# Need help w Apple Script reading text and copying files to new folder

Tags: applescript, pdf

I'm needing help with an AppleScript I've been using. The current script I use reads a text file that contains pdf file names, and then moves those to a different folder. This one works well but I really need it to just copy them instead of moving them. Could anyone possibly help with that?

```
# folders on different devices
set path2source to choose folder with prompt "Select the source folder" default location (path to desktop)
set path2dest to choose folder with prompt "Select the destination folder" default location (path to desktop)
set path2list to choose file with prompt "Select your textList" of type {"txt"}

set theList to paragraphs of (read path2list)

tell application "System Events"
    set theFiles to path of files of path2source
    set sourceList to {}
    repeat with aFile in theFiles
        if (name of disk item aFile) is in theList then
            set end of sourceList to my quotedIt(aFile)
        end if
    end repeat
end tell

do shell script "mv " & my recolle(sourceList, space) & space & quoted form of POSIX path of path2dest

#=====

on quotedIt(aFile)
    return quoted form of POSIX path of aFile
end quotedIt

#=====

on recolle(l, d)
    local oTIDs, t
    set {oTIDs, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, d}
    set t to l as text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oTIDs
    return t
end recolle
```

Comment: Is there a problem with using the `cp` command instead?